# Create gke cluster with existing shared vpc network using terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am still new to terraform. I am trying to create a gke cluster in cluster-project with network in network-project. It is a shared vpc. I am using the data module to import that network information;but it doesn't seems to be working. Everytime I run terraform apply; I get "Error: googleapi: Error 404: Not found: project "cluster-project" does not have a subnetwork named "terraform-test" in region "us-central1"., notFound"

cluster-project = project I am trying to build the cluster in
network-project = project that host the vpc and subnets

Here is my full main.tf file

```
data "google_compute_network" "main-default-vpc" {
  name    = "default"
  project = "network-project"
}

data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet-for-k8s" {
  name    = "terraform-test"
  project = "network-project"
  region  = "us-central1"
  self_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/terraform-test"

      }


resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  location       = "us-central1"
  project        = cluster-project
  name           = var.cluster_name
  node_locations = var.zones
  network        = data.google_compute_network.main-default-vpc.name
  subnetwork     = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet-for-k8s.name
  initial_node_count = "1"
  remove_default_node_pool = "true"

  master_authorized_networks_config {

    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      cidr_block   = "ip"
      display_name = ""
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "cloud-nat-2 "
      cidr_block   = "ip"
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "cloud-nat-3 "
      cidr_block   = "ip"
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "cloud-nat-4"
      cidr_block   = "ip"
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "cloud-nat-5"
      cidr_block   = "ip"
    }
  }
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet-for-k8s.secondary_ip_range.0.range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet-for-k8s.secondary_ip_range.1.range_name
  }
  monitoring_config {
    enable_components  = ["APISERVER","CONTROLLER_MANAGER","SYSTEM_COMPONENTS"]
  }
}



resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  name                               = "default"
  cluster                            = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  autoscaling {
    max_node_count                          = var.minnode
    min_node_count                          = var.maxnode
  }


  node_config {
    machine_type                       = "n1-standard-2"
    preemptible                        = false
    disk_type                          = "pd-standard"
    disk_size_gb                       = var.disksize

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually; this worked as is assuming all permissions issues are resolved. My issues was that there is an account like xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com to which I needed to give "network user" role. putting this here just in case someone else has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are having correct access permission of the shared VPC admin. Also, have a look at this google doc, might be helpful.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc